# How to let Jenkins git commit only if there are changes?

Tags: git, build, jenkins, bash

I have a Jenkins job that builds from a github.com repository's master branch with Maven (`mvn clean install`), then checks for license headers in Java files and missing NOTICE files, and adds them if necessary (`mvn license:format notice:generate`). Sometimes this will result in changed or added files, sometimes not.

Whenever there have any changes been made (by the license plugin) I want to push the changes to the github repo.

Now I'm having trouble figuring out how best to achieve that. I've added a shell build step after the Maven license plugin where I execute git commands:

```
git add . # Just in case any NOTICE files have been added
git commit -m "Added license headers"
```

`git add .` alone works, i.e., doesn't break the build, even if no files have been added. However, `git commit` breaks the build, if there aren't any changes at all.

I'm not concerned about pushing back to github, as I believe the Git Publisher post-build action can do this for me. Can someone please point me in the right direction for the git commit?

Comment: isn't there a way to get the timestamp of the latest change?

Comment: @ratchetfreak Thanks. You mean as in a) save the timestamp(s) before the license plug-in is run, and compare to timestamp(s) after it has been run? Sounds a bit expensive to me. Unless someone knows better :).

Answer (score 113, accepted):

```
git diff --quiet && git diff --staged --quiet || git commit -am 'Added license headers'
```

This command do exactly what is required, 'git commit only if there are changes', while the commands in the other answers do not: they only ignore any error of `git commit`.

Comment: It would be helpful to add parentheses here in case I don't know the bash operator precedence off the top of my head

Comment: In case there is a `git add` before this (like in the question) it should be sufficient to just run `git diff --staged --quiet || git commit -m '…'`. Otherwise, `git diff --quiet HEAD || git commit -am '…'` simplifies this solution.

Comment: `git add . && git diff --staged --quiet || git commit -m '...'` also works on a newly initialized repo

Comment: this fails for me in github actions on ubuntu with "fatal: ambiguous argument '||': unknown revision or path not in the working tree."

Answer (score 38):

You can also just catch the error code with an OR operator:

```
git commit -m "Added license headers" || echo "No changes to commit"
```

Comment: This is very nice for the CI setting. Leaves something useful in the logs to look for.

Comment: This is what I needed to resolve git issues in jenkins.

Answer (score 5):

To stop the build from breaking on the shell build step returning exit code `1` at any one point, e.g., when trying to make a git commit although there is nothing to commit, you can simply wrap the respective commands into an echo.

```
echo `git add -A && git commit -m "Added license headers"`
```

Now, whether there are untracked files to add to the index or not, and whether the working tree is dirty or clean, echo will return exit code `0`, as there will be some string to be `echo`ed.